# Why does the following error occurs when I gmake to build ratpoison on x86 Solaris 10 with gcc 3.4.3

Tags: gnulib

Why does the following error occurs when I gmake to build ratpoison on x86 Solaris 10 with gcc 3.4.3

Undefined first referenced symbol in file strcasestr     completions.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to ratpoison
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [ratpoison] Error 1

But   _GNU_SOURCE is in completions.c.

```
/*
 * Per POSIX strcasestr should be declared in strings.h
 * glibc declares it in string.h instead and needs 
 * _ GNU_SOURCE
 */
  #define _GNU_SOURCE
  #include <strings.h>
  #include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcasestr` is a GNU extension.  It's not part of Solaris libc.  Gnulib has an [implementation of `strcasestr`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/strcasestr.c) you could use.  See [the instructions for using `gnulib-tool`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Initial-import.html#Initial-import).